# Looping through an array gone wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a simple "app" whereby when a button is clicked, h1 changes to one of the jokes stored in an array. The JS code is as follow:

```
var jokes = [
    "Knock knock. Who’s there? Cow says. Cow says who? No, a cow says mooooo!",
    "Knock knock. Who’s there? Etch. Etch who? Bless you, friend."
]

jokes.forEach(function(item, index, array){
    $('.btn').click(function(){
       document.querySelector('.h1').innerHTML = jokes;  
    });
})
```

The functionality is there, but I think I got the logic a bit messed up. Whenever I click on the button, h1 changes to every single joke in the array, instead of one at a time, how do I go about fixing this? Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: => `.innerHTML = item`

Comment: So that fixes the fact that all of the items in the arrays are being showed, but upon clicking the button a second time, it's not showing the other joke. I know i'm missing something and i've probably studied it but I can't seem to remember, any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to display a random joke from the array or proceed sequentially starting from the first joke in the array? Do you want to keep appending jokes to the element or replace its content with the new joke?

Comment: Preferably randomly, but for studying purposes, anything will do as long as it picks from the array differently each time! I was looking for something that includes if...else.. instead of the answer shown below, which seems to be working, but it's not something I have encountered yet.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use just the jQuery without mixing vanilla.

By picking a random array in every click you could every time show 1 joke different:

**[Fiddle example using `if..else` statement](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/3nkuwdvj/1/)**.

**Random suggestion:**

```js
var jokes = [
  "Knock knock. Who’s there? Cow says. Cow says who? No, a cow says mooooo!",
  "Knock knock. Who’s there? Etch. Etch who? Bless you, friend."
]

$('.btn').click(function() {
  var random_index = Math.floor(Math.random() * jokes.length) + 0;
  $('.h1').html(jokes[random_index]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn">CHANGE</button>
<h1 class='h1'>INITIAL H1</h1>
```

**`if..else` suggestion:**

```js
var joke_index = 0;
var jokes = [
  "Knock knock. Who’s there? Cow says. Cow says who? No, a cow says mooooo!",
  "Knock knock. Who’s there? Etch. Etch who? Bless you, friend."
]

$('.btn').click(function() {

  if (joke_index === jokes.length - 1)
    joke_index = 0;
  else
    joke_index++;

  $('.h1').html(jokes[joke_index]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn">CHANGE</button>
<h1 class='h1'>INITIAL H1</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it works, but I haven't encountered "Math.floor(Math.random() * jokes.length) + 0;" before, so that wasn't really something I was aware of which is why I am looking for something in the lines of what I wrote, maybe something to do with if ... else..? Thanks!

Comment: @Muchkler: If you want a _random_  entry from the array, you're going to have to use `Math.random`. Consider this an opportunity to learn what the code does, isntead of "hiding" behind familiar code.

Comment: I see, and if I were to just display them in order, would there be a way to do that using if..else? To clarify, I wasn't really hiding, I'm willing to learn the code, I just want to know if there's another way of doing it with code i'm familiar with but can't get to work!

Comment: Yes it could be something like https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/3nkuwdvj/1/

Comment: Thanks for this, I appreciate it!

Comment: Glad I could help brother.

Answer (score -1):

You can use text method of JQ for this problem:
Following code is working fine. You just have to pass the random number to the index so that it will replace the value each time you will click on the button.

```
var jokes = [
    "Knock knock. Who’s there? Cow says. Cow says who? No, a cow says mooooo!",
    "Knock knock. Who’s there? Etch. Etch who? Bless you, friend."
]

jokes.forEach(function(item, index, array){
    $('.myBtn').click(function(){
       $('.myClass').text(jokes[0]);  
    });
})
```